# Error: The argument type 'Component' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Activity'

Tags: flutter, dart

When i pass `component` to `activity` in `ActivityWidget` i will get this error.

> Error: The argument type 'Component' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Activity'.

this is my code.

```
// a simple model class
abstract class Component {}

// a simple model class
class Activity extends Component {}

// a simple model class
class Quest extends Component {}

// a simple model class
class PrIPC {
  ComponentVertex? componentVertex;
  PrIPC({this.componentVertex});
}

// a simple model class
class ComponentVertex {
  Component? component;
  ComponentVertex({this.component});
}
```

```
// a simple flutter widget
class ActivityWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActivityWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.activity,
    required this.onConfirmSelected,
    required this.onCancelSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Activity activity;
  final VoidCallback onConfirmSelected;
  final VoidCallback onCancelSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(child: Text('Activity Widget'));
  }
}
```

### my Screen

```
class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPageView> createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  PrIPC myPrIPC = PrIPC(
    componentVertex: ComponentVertex(
      component: Activity(),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ActivityWidget(
      activity: myPrIPC.componentVertex!.component!,  // <== **I get ERROR in this line.**
      onConfirmSelected: () {},
      onCancelSelected: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

when i want to pass `Activity` to `ActivityWidget` from `PrPIC` i get this error. how can pass `component` of `PrPIC` class to `activity` of `ActivityWidget` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Component :

**What are the components in Flutter?**

```
Visual, behavioral, and motion-rich widgets implementing the Material Design guidelines.
App structure and navigation.
Buttons.
Input and selections.
Dialogs, alerts, and panels.
Information displays.
Layout.
```

What is Flutter activity?

```
Activity which displays a fullscreen Flutter UI. FlutterActivity is the simplest and most direct way to integrate Flutter within an Android app. FlutterActivity responsibilities. FlutterActivity maintains the following responsibilities: Displays an Android launch screen.
```

Comment: `Component` and `Activity` are simple model class with `id` and `text`. it's nothing special about them. i just want to pass `component` of `PrPIC` class to `activity` to `ActivityWidget`.